# Firebird SQL: StoredProc return null instead of assigned values

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird

I have a Firebird StoredProc run from a trigger before Insert and before update and also return 3 values. Those 3 values update 3 fields directly in the same table

I put a check at the SP beginning if the check is true I want to skip that SP so I used "suspend" and "Exit" but when I did that I found the 3 fields updates with null value. why is that ?

The trigger:

```
CREATE OR ALTER trigger trig1 for table1
active before insert or update position 2
AS
begin
  execute procedure my_proc1 new.f1, new.f2
  RETURNING_VALUES new.f3, new.f4, new.f5;
end
```

the StoredProc (it is very big I put only first lines):

```
begin
  if (COALESCE(Param1,0) = 1) then begin
    output1 = 0;
    output2 = 0;
    output3 = 0;

    exit;
  end
```

Even if I removed the IF block and kept everything else I dont get zeros in the 3 fields but NULL !!!. Please advise

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't posted enough of the stored procedure, it is hard to tell, but it looks like you're mixing selectable and executable procedures which is not recommended. Ie if you call the SP via `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` you should not have `SUSPEND` in it, if you have, then call it via `SELECT ... FROM SP`. FireBird is stricter in that regard in recent versions, althought I think it doesn't raise exception if you use "wrong calling mechanism"...

Anyway, if you call `EXIT` in selectable SP then it sets SQLCODE to 100 (end of record stream), IOW it doesn't set output values. So my suggestion is that you "clean up" your SP, either make it selectable (have `SUSPEND` in places where you want to return values and call it via `SELECT` statement) or make it executable (get rid of `SUSPEND` statements in it and call it via `EXECUTE`).